# How to use the already created object for opening fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android application i am using navigation drawer and i am opening fragments on drawer item click.I want to use the same object every time but couldn't find the proper way to do that.And it also takes some time(1-2 secs) to load and i am not using any api at this point.

Here's what i have done so far:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public String getTitleText() {
        return titleText;
    }

    public void setTitleText(String titleText) {
        this.titleText = titleText;
        titleTextTextView = (AvenirBookTextview) findViewById(R.id.home_title);
        titleTextTextView.setText(titleText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        HomeMenuButtonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.HomeMenuButtonLayout);
        HomeMenuButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_item);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_item_icon);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }

        // Set Header Right Drawer
        LayoutInflater inflaters = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup headertop = (ViewGroup) inflaters.inflate(R.layout.list_home_header, mDrawerList,
                false);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headertop, null, false);

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems, "yes");
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        openFragment(new HomeFragment());
        setTitleText("Home");

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                if (position == 1) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment1());
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment2());
                }

                if (position == 3) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment3());
                }

                if (position == 4) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment4());
                }
                if (position == 5) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment5());
                }

                if (position == 6) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment6());
                }

                if (position == 7) {
                    openFragment(new Fragment7());
                }
              }
        });
    }

    public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
}
```

And i have also tried :

```
        public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
                        transaction.show(fragment);
                    } else {
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
                        System.out.println("Number of Backstacks" + fragment.getClass().getName());
                    }

                    transaction.commit();
                }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

}
```

**Edit**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testApplication/com.testApplication.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:717)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1259)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6026)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the same object, when the older fragment is not visible in the UI? I doubt that is not a  good design?

Comment: Because i don't want to load data every time i click on menu.I want to load data only once and reuse it

Comment: Store the data in your activity, and when you call replaceFragment() set the data to the fragment object. Your data will be persist as long as your activity persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `replace()` method consider hiding and showing desired fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTagToBeShown));
    transaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag));
    transaction.commit();
```

And of course be sure to add all needed fragments at the beginning in the hidden state:

```
Fragment myFragment = new MyFragemnt();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment, SOME_TAG);
    transaction.hide(myFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: It gives exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

Comment: This error appears if 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag() == null, ensure that you added your fragments with correct tags.

Comment: Fragment myHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_container, myHomeFragment, "HOME");
        transaction.commit();

    FragmentTransaction transactionHome = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transactionHome.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HOME"));
        transactionHome.commit();
  
  **Am i doing it right?**

Comment: @Abhay, yes, but `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); transactionHome.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HOME")); transactionHome.commit();` should be called inside openFragment method. While the transaction which adds the fragemnt should be in `onCreate`. Could you show the full error stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, It Worked
Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    }
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

and Used like this

```
replaceFragment(new Fragment1(), false);
```

Comment: It is not working,its still using new object every time